# LWJGL move forward with only pitch and yaw

Tags: java, math, opengl, vector, lwjgl

So basically in my game I somehow managed to add moving right and then applied the opposite logic to move left, but I still have not managed to move forward nor backwards.
I only have a pitch and yaw to work with,
meaning I don’t have rotationX, Y or Z.
If you can help me calculate these that would also be cool if necessary.
So here is my current code:

```java
public class Camera {

    private final float maxPitch = 90.0F;
    private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    private float pitch;
    private float lastPitch;
    private float yaw;
    private float lastYaw;
    private float roll;
    private float forwardSpeed = 7.0f;
    private float backwardSpeed = 10.0f;
    private float sideSpeed = backwardSpeed;
    private float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    private float fallSpeed = 7.0f;
    private float sensitivity = 100;

    public Camera() {
    }

    public void update() {

        final double deltaTime = Main.getGame().deltaTime;
        final double forwardAmount = forwardSpeed * deltaTime;
        final double backAmount = backwardSpeed * deltaTime;

        final double sideAmount = backAmount;

        float pitch = (float) Math.toRadians(this.pitch);
        float yaw = (float) Math.toRadians(this.yaw);

        float xzLength = (float) (-0.44807361612);
        float dx = (float) (xzLength * Math.cos(yaw));
        float dz = (float) (xzLength * Math.sin(yaw));

        if (KeyUtils.isForwardDown()) {

        } else if (KeyUtils.isBackwardsDown()) {

        }

        if (KeyUtils.isLeftDown()) {
            position.x += dx * sideAmount;
            position.z += dz * sideAmount;
        } else if (KeyUtils.isRightDown()) {
            position.x -= dx * sideAmount;
            position.z -= dz * sideAmount;
        }

        if (KeyUtils.isJumping()) {
            position.y += jumpSpeed * deltaTime;
        } else if (KeyUtils.isSneaking()) {
            position.y -= fallSpeed * deltaTime;
        }

        float rotationSpeed = (float) (50F * deltaTime * sensitivity);
        this.yaw += Mouse.getDX() / rotationSpeed;
        if(pitch > maxPitch) {
            pitch = 90.0F;
            return;
        }
        this.pitch -= Mouse.getDY() / rotationSpeed;
    }

    public Vector3f getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3f position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public float getPitch() {
        return pitch;
    }

    public void setPitch(float pitch) {
        this.pitch = pitch;
    }

    public float getYaw() {
        return yaw;
    }

    public void setYaw(float yaw) {
        this.yaw = yaw;
    }

    public float getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(float roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public float getLastPitch() {
        return lastPitch;
    }

    public float getLastYaw() {
        return lastYaw;
    }
}
```

I also have a create view matrix method called every frame just like the camera.update() method

```java
public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {

    Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    viewMatrix.setIdentity();

    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);

    Vector3f cameraPos = camera.getPosition();
    Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-cameraPos.x, -cameraPos.y, -cameraPos.z);
    Matrix4f.translate(negativeCameraPos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);

    return viewMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few offers for you. Here is a youtube video which shows basic camera controls.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OO_yNzAuDe4

And here is some current code that is being used in my game:

```
using SharpDX;
using System;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX
{
    public enum CameraMode
    {
        FreeLook,
        Orbit
    }

    public class Camera
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of this camera
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The eye location of this camera
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 Location { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Pitch of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Pitch { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Yaw of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Yaw { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Roll of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Roll { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The NearZ of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public float NearZ { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The FarZ of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public float FarZ { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Field of View of this Camera, value should be
        /// between 0.70 and 1.20
        /// </summary>
        public float FieldOfView { get; set; }
        public float AspectRatio { get; set; }
        public float LookSpeed { get; set; }
        public float MoveSpeed { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if this Camera is currently accelerating.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsAccelerating { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The acceleration speed multiplier of this Camera.
        /// </summary>
        public float AccelerationMultiplier { get; set; }
        public CameraMode Mode { get; set; }
        public float ViewportWidth;
        public float ViewportHeight;

        /// <summary>
        /// The BoundingSphere of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public BoundingSphere Bounds
        {
            get
            {
                return new BoundingSphere()
                {
                    Center = this.Location,
                    Radius = 2.0f
                };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Target Vector of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 Target
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(
                    (float)Math.Sin(this.Yaw),
                    (float)Math.Tan(this.Pitch),
                    (float)Math.Cos(this.Yaw));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Frustum of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public BoundingFrustum Frustum
        {
            get
            {
                return new BoundingFrustum(this.ModelViewProjectionMatrix);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ModelViewMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.LookAtLH(this.Location, Location + Target, Up);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(FieldOfView, AspectRatio, NearZ, FarZ);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ModelViewProjectionMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return ModelViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix;
            }
        }

        //public CardinalDirectionType Direction
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        return VoidwalkerMath.GetCardinalDirection(VoidwalkerMath.ToDegrees(Yaw));
        //    }
        //}

        public Vector3 Forward
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(Pitch), 0, (float)Math.Sin(Pitch));
            }
        }

        public Vector3 Right
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(Forward.X, 0, -Forward.X);
            }
        }

        public Vector3 Up
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(-(float)Math.Sin(Roll), (float)Math.Cos(Roll), 0);
            }
        }

        public Camera()
        {

        }

        public Camera(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Location = new Vector3();
        }

        public void ToOrigin()
        {
            Transform(Vector3.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        public void Transform(Vector3 location, float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
        {
            this.Location = location;
            this.Pitch = pitch;
            this.Yaw = yaw;
            this.Roll = roll;
        }

        public float GetCurrentMoveSpeed()
        {
            if (IsAccelerating)
            {
                return this.MoveSpeed * this.AccelerationMultiplier;
            }
            return this.MoveSpeed;
        }

        public void TranslateLeft(float deltaTime)
        {
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                Location.X - (float)Math.Sin(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime,
                Location.Y,
                Location.Z - (float)Math.Cos(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateRight(float deltaTime)
        {
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                Location.X + (float)Math.Sin(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime,
                Location.Y,
                Location.Z + (float)Math.Cos(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateForward(float deltaTime)
        {
            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateBackward(float deltaTime)
        {

            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TransformYawPitch(float dx, float dy)
        {
            Yaw += dx * LookSpeed;
            Pitch -= dy * LookSpeed;
            const float pitchClamp = 1.56f;
            if (Pitch <= -pitchClamp)
            {
                Pitch = -pitchClamp;
            }
            if (Pitch >= pitchClamp)
            {
                Pitch = pitchClamp;
            }
        }

        public void TranslateUp(float deltaTime)
        {
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X,
                this.Location.Y + GetCurrentMoveSpeed() * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z); // TODO implement up/down based upon roll orientation.
        }

        public void TranslateDown(float deltaTime)
        {
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X,
                this.Location.Y - GetCurrentMoveSpeed() * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z);
        }

        public void LookAt(Vector3 location, float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
        {
            this.Location = location;
            this.Pitch = pitch;
            this.Yaw = yaw;
            this.Roll = roll;
        }

        public void SetAspectRatio(int width, int height)
        {
            this.ViewportWidth = width;
            this.ViewportHeight = height;
            this.AspectRatio = width / (float)height;
        }
    }
}
```

That code itself will only help you for looking at implementation details. I can't provide a minimal camera example that shows initialization and mouse input right now. I suggest watching the youtube video, because it's something I started with years ago and modified from over time. That tutorial is also using LWJGL, much as your requirements asked for. (API is really moot though, considering frameworks are typically interchangeable anyway).

The code for calculating movement forward and backward is (This may end up being left and right depending on how your scene is setup; remember, direction is completely subjective):

```
public void TranslateForward(float deltaTime)
        {
            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateBackward(float deltaTime)
        {

            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }
```

Actually, here is my mouse input code. You won't find anything online that looks similar to this, because I am actaully querying raw mouse input. Most people don't do that, and it's why most examples lead to really bad "camera snapping" on mouse down.

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            this.CurrentMouseLocation = new Point(args.X, args.Y);
            if (IsMouseLookEnabled)
            {
                MouseUpdate[] updates = Mouse.GetBufferedData();
                if (updates != null && updates.Length > 0)
                {
                    int xAccumulation = 0;
                    int yAccumulation = 0;
                    if (updates != null && updates.Length > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < updates.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (updates[i].IsButton)
                            {
                                // Reject Buffered Data
                                return;
                            }
                            if (updates[i].Offset == MouseOffset.X)
                            {
                                xAccumulation += updates[i].Value;
                            }
                            if (updates[i].Offset == MouseOffset.Y)
                            {
                                yAccumulation += updates[i].Value;
                            }
                        }
                        float dx = MathUtil.DegreesToRadians(xAccumulation) * 0.25F;
                        float dy = MathUtil.DegreesToRadians(yAccumulation) * 0.25F;
                        Camera.TransformYawPitch(dx, dy);
                    }
                }
                Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(_mouseLockLocation.X, _mouseLockLocation.Y);
                this.CurrentMouseLocation = _mouseLockLocation;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I will do so tomorrow as I am not on a computer right now but I highly appreciate the answer and how you took time and effort to answer it in so much detail and link your code and the video and some base knowledge on movement. I really suck at vector math. Can’t thank you enough.

Comment: I also didn’t need a quick answer, had time untill tomorrow, i saw people here are really helpful so I post here.

Comment: @purplex No problem, dude. The truth is, there's a hundred ways you can do this, and none of them are equal. This is one of those coding things that you have to grind away at until it's perfect.

Comment: For some reason i double checked the buffered data for being null and empty twice in that look code. No idea why i did that. Was probably drinking that night, or something.